# ORA-017779 : cannot modify a column which maps to non key-preserved table

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

How can I solve this error:

> ORA-017779 : cannot modify a column which maps to non key-preserved table.

My Code:

```
UPDATE   (SELECT SOBS034.T1 as OLD, SOBS063.T1 as NEW
          FROM SOBS034 
          INNER JOIN SOBS063  ON SOBS034.ID = SOBS063.ID
          where  SOBS034.ID='111000' AND SOBS063.T2='' ) t
SET t.OLD =t.NEW
```

Answer (score 3):

To update a `JOIN`, Oracle needs to be absolutely sure that for each row of the table you are trying to update, there will be **at most** one row of the joined table.

Here you'll be able to update the join **if and only if** `SOBS063.ID` is unique (explicitely declared by a unique constraint/pk).

If somehow `SOBS063.ID` is unique for this record with your join condition but is not declared as such, you won't be able to use this method. You could however transform this DML into an equivalent `MERGE`, something like this:

```
MERGE INTO SOBS034 a
USING SOBS063 b
ON (a.id = b.id AND a.ID='111000' AND b.T2 IS NULL)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.t1 = b.t1;
```

By the way `SOBS063.T2=''` is never true in Oracle right now.

Comment: thanks for your reply.But, I get this error again. "ORA-00905 Missing Error".

Comment: You haven't provided: CREATE TABLE statement, INSERT statement so I can't really help you

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a unique index on SOBS034 (ID) and SOBS063 (ID).